# Check missed doctrine migrations

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, migration, symfony

Help, if it is possible, to check missed doctrine migrations (Symfony 3) via bash script (for apache ant).

I've try to find some solutions, but nothing interesting, maybe somebody already has the same problem.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you looking for? Some migrations that is not yet executed?

Comment: check Entities and look if something lost in migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution.
The best way is to make a good map by entities